# the "real spectrum" of an operator acting on a real Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space over the field $\mathbb{R}$, and denote by $\mathcal{L}(X)$ the space of continuous linear operators acting on $X$.  The spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ is defined as the set of all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ for which the complexification shift $\lambda-T_\mathbb{C}$ is not invertible in $\mathcal{L}(X_\mathbb{C})$.  (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121437/complexifying-a-real-banach-space-and-its-dual) for the definition of a complexification.) *However, I am interested in invertibility in the real setting.*

The **real spectrum** of $T$, denoted $\sigma_\mathbb{R}(T)$, is the set of all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a-T$ does not have an inverse in $\mathcal{L}(X)$.  It is the complement of the **real resolvent**, defined as
\begin{equation}\rho_\mathbb{R}(T):=\left\{a\in\mathbb{R}:\text{ there is }\;S\in\mathcal{L}(X)\;\text{ such that }\;S(a-T)=(a-T)S=I_X\right\},\end{equation}
where $I_X\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ is the identity operator ($I_Xx=x\;\forall x\in X$).

**Question 1.** I suspect (although I haven't verified it yet) that $\sigma_\mathbb{R}(T)=\mathbb{R}\cap\sigma(T)$. Is there a reference for this?

**Question 2.** Suppose $r\in\partial\sigma_\mathbb{R}(T)$ and $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq\rho_\mathbb{R}(T)$ with $a_n\to r$.  Is it true that $\|(a_n-T)^{-1}\|\to\infty$?

I would also be interested in any good literature on the real spectrum, if it is available.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should require that a complexification of $X$ exists. [As you can see here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-01/S0002-9939-1952-0047252-8/S0002-9939-1952-0047252-8.pdf), this is not always true neither in finite nor in infinite dimension.

Comment: The complexification $X_\mathbb{C}$ of a real Banach space $X$ always exists. It is just the direct sum $X_\mathbb{C}=X\oplus iX$ endowed the vector space operations coordinate-wise addition and $(a+ib)(x_1\oplus ix_2)=(ax_1-bx_2)\oplus i(bx_1+ax_2)$, and with the norm $\|x_1\oplus ix_2\|_{X_\mathbb{C}}=\sup_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}\|x_1\sin\theta+x_2\cos\theta\|_X$. What you are referencing is the fact that there exist *complex* Banach spaces $\mathcal{Y}$ which are not isomorphic to $Y_\mathbb{C}$ for any real Banach space $Y$. It's a really cool result but not applicable here.

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Maybe you could add to the post the definition of the complexification, to prevent further misunderstandings. (This is an interesting question!)

Comment: Sure, sounds good. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot contribute references. But, regarding question 1, note that for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, you have that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if $T_{\mathbb C}-\lambda I$ is invertible. Then 
$$
\sigma_\mathbb{R}(T)=\mathbb{R}\cap\sigma(T).
$$

To show the above invertibility, let us write $T$ and $T_{\mathbb C}$. If $ST=TS=I$, then 
$$
S_{\mathbb C}T_{\mathbb C}(x+iy)=S_{\mathbb C}(Tx+iTy)=STx+iSTy=x+iy.
$$
In a similar way we obtain $T_{\mathbb C}S_{\mathbb C}=I$.

If $S'T_{\mathbb C}=T_{\mathbb C}S'=I$, then define $Sx$ to be the "real part" of $S'(x+i0)$. Then
$$
STx=S'(Tx+i0)=S'(Tx+iT0)=S'T_{\mathbb C}(x+i0)=x+i0=x,
$$
and 
$$
TSx=TSx+iT0=T_{\mathbb C}(Sx+i0)=T_{\mathbb C}S'(x+i0)=x+i0=x
$$

---

Regarding question 2, suppose $\|(a_n-T)^{-1}\|\leq c$ for all $n$. Then since $r-a_n\to0$, for $n$ big enough we have 
$$
\|(a_n-T)^{-1}\|\leq\frac1{|r-a_n|}.
$$
But then, for $n$ big enough
$$\tag{1}
\|(r-T)-(a_n-T)\|=|r-a_n|\leq\|(a_n-T)^{-1}\|^{-1}.
$$
Since $a_n-T$ is invertible, this would imply that $r-T$ is invertible, a contradiction. So 
$$
\|(a_n-T)^{-1}\|\to\infty.
$$